# org-mode: Duplicate tag groups when filtering agenda

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, tags, filtering

When filtering `org-agenda` by tags using `org-agenda-filter-by-tag`, tag groups specified in `org-tag-alist` show up multiple times.

`org-agenda-filter-by-tag` uses the variable `org-tag-alist-for-agenda`, which is set dynamically based on all available tags in all org buffers (I think). According to `org--tag-add-to-alist`, which is used to set `org-tag-alist-for-agenda`, duplicate tag groups are not removed, by design. However, this causes groups I have defined in `org-tag-alist` to show up as many times as I have org buffers.

Are there any (known) easy ways around this issue, to avoid a very long list of tags when filtering the agenda?